# How to create and show values from a select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list that a user can select from:

```
NOTIFY = [['Only in reports', 'only_in_reports'],['Immediately', 'immediately']]

<%= f.select(:notifications, NOTIFY) %>
```

The key/second value gets stored in the database, e.g., `'only_in_reports'`.

When I display the value in the show view it displays the key, e.g., '`only_in_reports`' instead of '`Only in reports`'.

How I select and display the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

May this will work for you.

```
<%= f.select :notifications, options_for_select(NOTIFY.html_safe)%>
```